# Where is the memory leak when freeing this nested struct?

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, memory-leaks, malloc

I'm trying to implement a Barnes-Hutt tree in C and I'm having an issue when freeing the tree.

The nodes in the tree are as follows:

```
struct node {
    int is_external;
    quad q;
    body *b;

    node *nw;
    node *ne;
    node *sw;
    node *se;
};
```

and the function I use to free them is

```
void free_node(node *n) {
    // free subnodes
    if (n->nw != NULL) {
        free_node(n->nw);
    }
    if (n->ne != NULL) {
        free_node(n->ne);
    }
    if (n->sw != NULL) {
        free_node(n->sw);
    }
    if (n->se != NULL) {
        free_node(n->se);
    }

    // free this node's body
    if (!n->is_external) {
        free(n->b);
    }
    free(n);
}
```

(I'm not freeing the bodies of external nodes because they are kept for the next iteration of the simulation).

When I check for memory leaks however, I get

```
72 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 24 of 51
   at 0x100111CF5: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-9f4f524/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
   by 0x100001B95: subnode (bh_tree.c:70)
   by 0x100002413: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:165)
   by 0x100001693: main (sim.c:115)

72 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 25 of 51
   at 0x100111CF5: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-9f4f524/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
   by 0x100001B95: subnode (bh_tree.c:70)
   by 0x100001E64: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:108)
   by 0x100002675: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:188)
   by 0x100001693: main (sim.c:115)

72 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 26 of 51
   at 0x100111CF5: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-9f4f524/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
   by 0x100001B95: subnode (bh_tree.c:70)
   by 0x10000251D: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:173)
   by 0x100001F97: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:118)
   by 0x100001693: main (sim.c:115)

72 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 27 of 51
   at 0x100111CF5: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-9f4f524/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
   by 0x100001B95: subnode (bh_tree.c:70)
   by 0x100002627: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:181)
   by 0x10000209B: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:126)
   by 0x100002675: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:188)
   by 0x100001F97: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:118)
   by 0x100001693: main (sim.c:115)

72 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 28 of 51
   at 0x100111CF5: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-9f4f524/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
   by 0x100001B95: subnode (bh_tree.c:70)
   by 0x10000206C: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:124)
   by 0x100002675: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:188)
   by 0x10000209B: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:126)
   by 0x100002675: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:188)
   by 0x100001F97: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:118)
   by 0x100001693: main (sim.c:115)

72 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 29 of 51
   at 0x100111CF5: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-9f4f524/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
   by 0x100001B95: subnode (bh_tree.c:70)
   by 0x100002170: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:132)
   by 0x100001693: main (sim.c:115)

72 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 30 of 51
   at 0x100111CF5: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-9f4f524/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
   by 0x100001B95: subnode (bh_tree.c:70)
   by 0x100002627: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:181)
   by 0x100001E93: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:110)
   by 0x100001693: main (sim.c:115)

72 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 31 of 51
   at 0x100111CF5: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-9f4f524/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
   by 0x100001B95: subnode (bh_tree.c:70)
   by 0x100002627: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:181)
   by 0x10000219F: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:134)
   by 0x100002675: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:188)
   by 0x100001E93: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:110)
   by 0x100001693: main (sim.c:115)

72 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 32 of 51
   at 0x100111CF5: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-9f4f524/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
   by 0x100001B95: subnode (bh_tree.c:70)
   by 0x100002309: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:157)
   by 0x10000219F: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:134)
   by 0x100002675: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:188)
   by 0x10000219F: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:134)
   by 0x100002675: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:188)
   by 0x100001E93: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:110)
   by 0x100001693: main (sim.c:115)

72 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 33 of 51
   at 0x100111CF5: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-9f4f524/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
   by 0x100001B95: subnode (bh_tree.c:70)
   by 0x10000206C: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:124)
   by 0x100002675: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:188)
   by 0x10000219F: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:134)
   by 0x100002675: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:188)
   by 0x10000219F: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:134)
   by 0x100002675: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:188)
   by 0x100001E93: insert_in_node (bh_tree.c:110)
   by 0x100001693: main (sim.c:115)
```

all of which point to the following `malloc`

```
    node n_sub;
    n_sub.is_external = 1;
    n_sub.q = subquad(n.q, k);
    n_sub.nw = NULL;
    n_sub.ne = NULL;
    n_sub.sw = NULL;
    n_sub.se = NULL;
    n_sub.b = malloc(sizeof(body));
    *n_sub.b = (body) {.id=EMPTY};

    return n_sub;
}
```

but I'm fairly certain I was freeing all of these correctly. Any ideas where it could be going wrong?

Comment: We need to see a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). By definition you don't know where the problem is. So by selectively showing the code it is possible you have removed the actual root cause. So please construct a minimal example that we can run ourselves to see the problem. "I'm not freeing the bodies of external node": for example, how can we be sure that is done correctly and that those bodies are eventually freed. We can't, without all the relevant code.

Comment: How is struct `body` defined? Is its size 72? Do you ever set back `is_external` to 0?

Comment: It's a good practice to null out pointers after you free the memory they point to; this will help catch a lot of mistakes.

Comment: Note: If `n->nw->se == n` then this is going to break sooner or later. Better split it up then into a layer doing your algorithm stuff (likely using the `nw` etc links) and a layer doing memory allocation (perhaps keeping all nodes in an array).

Comment: @SteveFriedl Thanks for the tip. I'll make sure to do that in the future.

Comment: @kaylum Yeah I realised that it's a bit of a mess. There were so many relevant bits of code and I didn't want to put them all in

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `valgrind` is always complaining about the same `malloc`:

> `at 0x100111CF5: malloc (`...`)`
>          `by 0x100001B95: subnode (bh_tree.c:70)`

And the only `malloc` you point to in your code is at a guess the implementation of `subnode`:

```
node n_sub;
n_sub.is_external = 1;
//...
n_sub.b = malloc(sizeof(body));
```

But, in your `free_node` function you only call `free` if `is_external` is false:

```
if (!n->is_external) {
    free(n->b);
}
```

So, you need to suspect whatever code path you think is setting `is_external` to false is not always (or perhaps is never) called.